# Capturing Client Info such as MAC address, IP, etc. C#

Tags: c#, security, arp

After doing some research, i am reaching out for some further help or recommendations. If i have a website sitting out on an external network(public facing) and i want to capture information about what client is requesting access to the website, is there a consistent way of doing this regardless of browser or device?

ActiveX is a no go due to install requirement.
ARP seemed promising until it said it doesn't work with routers(sigh)
Using the System.Net and grabbing the MAC addresses looked ok but appeared to also require the clients to be in the same subnet which in this wouldn't work.
Grabbing the IP of the request and then going after the MAC address with that IP seemed promising but fell short when routers come in to play as you get those devices instead of the phone/pc etc.

Is there a way for me to capture the MAC or IP of a client that is outside our network?

Comment: MAC address is next to useless in a public facing website, do you really need to capture it? IP address can be tricky due to proxy servers too.

Comment: The MAC address can not be retrieved easily since it's not used for communication over the internet. The IP adress can usually be found out.

Comment: I am just wanting to be able to capture the client that's using the site. This task seems more and more unrealistic. :(